# Blazor QuickGrid: Reset virtualized grid scroll position with new data source

Tags: blazor, quickgrid

I'm very new to Blazor, and equally new to [QuickGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/quickgrid?view=aspnetcore-7.0) component (which is in preview). I'm not really sure if this question is a general Blazor question, or a QuickGrid question!

In short my question is:

> How do I reset the position of a virtualized QuickGrid when I get completely new data?

I have a customer search, and displaying results as a virtualized list.

I have a `QuickGrid` with an `ItemsProvider`.

```
<QuickGrid @ref="OrdersQuickGrid" ItemsProvider="@ordersProvider" 
           Virtualize="true" ItemSize="@itemHeight">
```

When a search is triggered a new `ordersProvider` is created, and the request is captured by the closure to run again after the user scrolls. This works fine and doesn't even seem to need `RefreshDataAsync()`.

```
public async Task SearchOrders(SearchOrdersCriteria criteria)
{
    SearchOrdersCriteria currentSearch = new SearchOrdersCriteria
    {
        SmartSearchString = criteria.SmartSearchString
    };

    // create new orders provider
    ordersProvider = async providerRequest =>
    {
        var result = await RunSearch(providerRequest, currentSearch);

        return result;
    };

    // refresh data - no effect with either of these
    // StateHasChanged();        
    // await OrdersQuickGrid.RefreshDataAsync();
}
```

The problem is if I search for `Steve` and then scroll down and run a new search for `Mary` the scroll position will remain where it was before.

As per the [QuickGrid sample for virtualization](https://aspnet.github.io/quickgridsamples/virtualizing) I had to create the css to handle the scroll container and then the component does all the calculation to see what the items are.

There's two ways I can think of to reset the grid:

- Completely redraw it and create a new one. (not sure how to do this without a hack)
- Use Javascript to reset the scroll position. (doesn't seem very Blazor like)

I want to make sure I'm not missing something. I couldn't even find how this would be done with the normal [Virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-7.0) component. Since I'm new to Blazor I don't yet know when I would typically need to reach for JS - but this seems like a case where I shouldn't have to.

Comment: This might be a weak point of QuickGrid. See if you can add a mre (create some data in a for-loop). Also, make clear if you are using Blazor 7 or 8preview.

Comment: I'm using the latest v8 preview. It's more of a conceptual question so I didn't make an example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seems to work at least as a temporary solution.

- Set an items provider with no items.
- Call `RefreshDataAsync`.
- Set the new items provider with the new search.

This triggers the browser to reset the scroll position since there are no items.

I actually don't understand how it works though! Since `ordersProvider` is a component parameter I wouldn't have expected it to be set in time for the `RefreshDataAsync` call.

But it seems to work :-) I welcome better (especially from Microsoft) solutions or explanation of how it works!

```
public async Task SearchOrders(SearchOrdersCriteria criteria)
{
    SearchOrdersCriteria currentSearch = new SearchOrdersCriteria
    {
        SmartSearchString = criteria.SmartSearchString
    };

    // reset grid by setting items provider to an empty list
    ordersProvider = async providerRequest =>
    {
        return new GridItemsProviderResult<CRMOrder>
        {
            Items = new CRMOrder[0],
            TotalItemCount = 0
        };
    };

    await OrdersQuickGrid.RefreshDataAsync();

    // create new orders provider
    ordersProvider = async providerRequest =>
    {
        var result = await RunSearch(providerRequest, currentSearch);

        return result;
    };
}
```